# Reduce fireplace vent soot on house siding

Tags: gas, fireplace, fire

We've noticed a buildup of soot in the past couple months on the siding of our new-to-us house where the gas fireplace vents. Should we be concerned? Is there any way to reduce the buildup besides not using the fireplace?[image: side of house]

Comment: use a extender to move it further from the wall

Comment: @Ruskes - that needs to be fixed at source, not 'hidden'. It's burning wrong mixture; check carbon monoxide levels too. [Oddly, in the UK, CO detectors are compulsory in rentals, but not private houses; most of which don't have one]

Comment: Thank you both! I think we'll try checking on the ratios first and report back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have the fireplace serviced to adjust the fuel/air ratio. If you're burning gas and making soot, it's too rich (excess fuel, not enough air.)

Comment: Thank you! I'll report back when I know more.

Comment: I believe this answer is correct. We've had a professional service the fireplace. They said the shutter was closed all the way which increased the flame height but contributed to the sooting. Also, the logs were misplaced. We haven't cleaned the side of the house yet but the professional recommended power washing or just painting over it.